# Linq to SQL get record with Max date value

Tags: linq-to-sql, performance, max

If I was to write as follows...

```
var latest = _records.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).First();
```

Is this ordering the complete set? Or is Linq clever enough to work out that you're only looking for the max value? Is there a more efficient way of writing the above?

Comment: Why don't you open the sql profiler, create a new trace and trace the sql commands. You will be able to see what sql statement or statements are being called.  I don't know the answer myself so this is the approach that I would take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, LINQ to SQL is smart enough to do the work on the database side.  Your snippet will result in SQL like `SELECT TOP (1) ... ORDER BY ...`.

(This is assuming that in your snippet `_records` represents a `System.Data.Linq.Table<T>` or something `IQueryable`, etc.)

As far as the optimal way to write the query, you might consider `FirstOrDefault()` if it's possible your table won't contain any records, in which case `First()` will throw an exception.